# No Encoder found while listing component names and model using IOMX but still android can record .mp4 files with H264 encoded frames

Tags: android, media-player, stagefright

I have been trying to list out all supported codec in android device using IOMX as shown [here](http://www.slideshare.net/RaghavanVenkateswaran/iomx-in-android) by binding with media player service. I got my code working and get the list of components. But I observed that there were no encoder component. Only all decoder component were listed. Then I go to inbuilt camera application provided by android and started recording video which was stored in mp4 file format. When I check the mp4 file's codec information from VLC player, It showed "H264 mpeg4 part10 avc". So here comes my doubt. If there is no component listed for h264/avc encoding then how android can encode frames in h264 format?

Any Suggestion?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In android distribution, there is a suite of codecs that are bundled by Google commonly referred to as "plain vanilla codecs". In case of H.264, there is an encoder bundled, whose sources are at `frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/codecs/avc/enc/`. Hence, when you encode from the camera, this default codec is used to encode the frames. To verify the same, you could enable the logs in `OMXCodec` or `ACodec` and observe that the name of the encoder component is `OMX.google.h264.encoder`.

The complete list of codecs is available in `SoftOMXPlugin.cpp` at `frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/omx/`

Comment: Yes, you should be able to. From a Stagefright point of view, the software based plain vanilla component is similar to a user integrated component.

Comment: Do you suggest that it is better to select libstagefright compare to IOMX from media player service for media operations and component listing?

Comment: Yes. For easier integration, please use either `OMXCodec` or `ACodec` objects to abstract your underlying codec. If your application is a higher level software, then you may want to consider `MediaCodec` object abstraction which is a layer above `ACodec`.